# Can't access my vector variables in different conditions

Tags: c++, if-statement, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to do creating objects in a one condition and listing this objects in another condition, but it doesn't work.

```
void fillVector(vector<Account>& newcreateAccObj){ 

    string name;
    string password;

    cout<<"Enter your surname:"<<endl;
    cin>>name;
    cout<<"Enter your password:"<<endl;
    cin>>password;

    Account newAcc(name,password);
    newcreateAccObj.push_back(newAcc);
    cout<<endl;     
}
```

This works fine.

```
void printVector(vector<Account>& newcreateAccObj){

    unsigned int size=newcreateAccObj.size();

    for(unsigned int i=0;i<size;i++){

        cout<<"Account"<<i+1<<endl;
        cout<<"-----------"<<endl;
        newcreateAccObj[i].getId();
        newcreateAccObj[i].getName();
        cout<<endl;     
    }   
}
```

This works fine too when I execute these 2 functions in same condition.

But when I do this:

```
int main(){
int whileCondition=-1;
string girisSecim;

vector<Account>  createAccObj;


while(whileCondition==-1){

    cout<<"--------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"??????????????????????????????????????????????????????"<<endl;
    cout<<"1-create acc                     2-transferring"<<endl;
    cout<<"3-enter acc                      4-exit"<<endl;
    cout<<"--------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;


    cin>>girisSecim;



        if(girisSecim=="1"){

            fillVector(createAccObj);  //BURDA OBJE OLUSTURULUYOR

        }

        else if(girisSecim=="2"){


        printVector(createAccObj);

        }

        else if(girisSecim=="3"){





        }

        else if(girisSecim=="4"){
            return 0;

        }

        else{
            cout<<"Hatali tuslama."<<endl;
        }


        whileCondition=0;

        cout<<"Programa devam etmek icin -1'i, cikmak icin herhangi bir seyi tuslayiniz."<<endl;

        cin>>whileCondition;
}
```

Edit: I edited the main part.

I choose option 1 first. I create my object and returning the select menu, after that I choose option 2 and it gives me a blank output.

Comment: `createAccObj` is not the same vector the second time, but we can't know why.

Comment: Why not use range for loops?

Comment: i dont get it clearly @LogicStuff can you be more spesific ?

Comment: There's relevant code to this problem that's not present in your post - please include some more code context around where you call the `fillVector` and `printVector` functions (see [mcve]).

Comment: i added full main part @hnefatl

Comment: I've made a reproducible version online [here](https://ideone.com/gdeR0t) - when you said "blank output", did you mean that it **just didn't print the name and id**? Because if so, that's a very different error to what you reported, and is caused simply because you're doing `newcreateAccObj[i].getId();`, not `std::cout << newcreateAccObj[i].getId();`.

Comment: @hnefatl you are right it wasnt printing the name and id , sorry for wasting your time i added cout<< parts and it did work fine.

Comment: Off-topic:  You could use a `switch` statement if you read the input as an integer instead of a string.

Answer (score -1):

follow the lifetime of createAccObj.

it seems like you do not send the same vector to both functions.

I will have a guess, your code looks like this:

```
while (input}(
    vector<Account> createAccObj;
    if(input=="1"){
       fillVector(createAccObj);
    }else if(input=="2"){
       printVector(createAccObj);
    }
```

here, on each iteration, new vector is created, so when you try to print, you print empty vector.
If this is the case, simply, remove the vector deceleration outside the loop.

Edit:
looking into the code again, seems like you forgot `cout` in `newcreateAccObj[i].getId();` and newcreateAccObj[i].getName();

Comment: i edited the main part.Could you look again ?  @yosim